# Facebook graph api issue while fetching user uploaded video

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a `Facebook graph api` to fetch user uploaded video by `setReadPermission` `user_videos`.

I got the response of uploaded/live video in a `embed_html` `<iframe>` which supports for web integration of video.

Then I tried the followed the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/video/)  to get video source file or link to play it in Android `Videoview`.
But `GraphResponse` object returns only `Description`, uploaded time and ID only.
What I can do to get the video details.

```
Response:
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"description":"Test video","updated_time":"2016-12-13T06:21:00+0000","id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}, error: null}
```

I am looking for a video source file in the format of **mp4** so that I can play it in android Videoview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook JS SDK's FB.api('/me') method doesn't return the fields i expect in Graph API v2.4+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584850/facebook-js-sdks-fb-api-me-method-doesnt-return-the-fields-i-expect-in-gra)

Answer (score 0):

I went through the following post which helps me to get the video source file to play in android native video player.

[Get url from uploaded video on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526877/get-url-from-uploaded-video-on-facebook?rq=1)